# Between an array or a singly linked list, which one is the better choice to implement a stack?

Tags: data-structures

Considering how fast it implements pop() and how it manages memory, I've read they're both bad, but I think the linked list is better because you can free up memory when you pop() the top of the stack, as opposed to not being able to resize the array after popping.

Comment: Why would you need to resize the array if popping ? The only reason you would resize the array is if you want to push but there isn't enough space. I would choose the array, you create a big one, and you have an index moving when you push and pop.
For example, when you write assembly programs, the stack pointer is only an index and your memory is the array

Comment: These depend entirely on the use-case. Neither are inherently bad or good

Comment: @omar I only need to consider the speed of the pop() implementation, and how efficiently it uses memory to choose between array and linked list (see description). If I use an array, would I not waste memory after popping?

Comment: Pop are constant with array, push are most of the time constant (except if you have to realloct to make the array bigger). So yes, you will have unused space but if you know that your program will perform  a lot `push` and `pop`, it's worthy. So in my opinion, it's the best option

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: It depends.

I.e. in Java there are ArrayList and LinkedList collections available.

- If you'd prefer ArrayList - you'd have potential performance problems
  during pushing (when capacity is big enough Java creates another
  array twice bigger and copies existing one there).
- If you'd prefer LinkedList - you'd loose some time on adding (usually tiny amount) used for creating link to previous element.

Also, there're some memory limitations (as I remember). LinkedList's requirements are a bit less strict.

So, you need to know how List/Array are implemented in your exact environment.